# Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet.jar

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I created project using Jersey archetype, I cannot build this project as below dependencies are not resolving.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have `${jersey.version}` property in your pom file?

Comment: Yes Alex, i resolved problem by using jersey.version = 1.19.1

Answer (score 8):

Most probably this might be due to the jersey version you have configured is not available.
Update the property for Jersey version in the pom.xml as below or your desired version:

```
<jersey.version>1.19.1</jersey.version>
```

It will resolve all dependencies.

If you still face issues, please explain the error you get in detail.

Comment: Those who downvote pls add a comment with the reason. I will try to answer

Answer (score 0):

By default archetype is using jersey.version.1.20-SNAPSHOT, dependencies will download once correct version is specified in pom.